# Incompability of kpfonts and hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, kpfonts

I use `hyperref` with the optional argument `breaklinks=true`.
I later wanted to inlcude kpfonts via:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

What I got after compiling was the following error message:

> ! pdfTeX error (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pd
>   fstartlink.
>   \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox
>
> \fi \fi
>
> l.278
>
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>   Transcript written on pirates.log.
>   texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).

When I put all the existing references in my .tex-file into a box (for example by framing them in a `\fbox{}` then the compiler did his job, but (of course) without breaking the links.

Has anybody an idea what the problem might be? (I hope the part of the error-code I posted is sufficient...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — The usual rule (with its exceptions) is: Load `hyperref` last. From what you say in your question, it seems you load it before other packages. This has often created issues in the past. A MWE would surely help to sorten that out.

Comment: Avoid the link that is broken across pages.

Comment: I refrained from the MWE at first, because I set my references (which apparently cause the problems) via macros and felt like asking about general incompabilities at first (I didn't find any posts - what I found couldn't fix my problem).

However, I was about to create a MWE for you now and I incidentally found out that the `draft`-mode (given as optional argument in `\documentclass[]{scrbook}`) caused the compiling failure. **With `draft` "turned off" everything goes just fine...**

@HeikoOberdiek: Thought about that too. Is there a general way to prevent that links are broken across pages?

Comment: (Out of characters...)
Plus, any idea why `draft` is the problem?

Comment: 1) `draft` disables `hyperref`'s links. 2) There is not a general way to prevent links that are broken across pages.

Comment: ad 1) If they get disabled, why are they a problem at all?
ad 2) Hmm... well, ploughing through "manually" then, I'd say...

Besides, thank you very much for the quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

It's important that `draft`-mode is set `false` in `\documentclass[draft=false]{<class>}` (it is by default, in fact), then `kpfonts` will load.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 0):

At first it seemed that broken links (...`hyperref`) cause an error. However, it turned out that for some reason `draft`-mode needs to be turned *off* when using `MikTex`. I started to use `TeX Live` recently and `kpfonts` works just fine (*with* `draft` mode, broken links and so forth...)